# How to add WooCommerce SKU to search query?

Tags: search

I have issue adding the `meta_value` in search query for the WooCommerce SKU. By default, the search by SKU only work on the admin.

I would like to make the frontend search accepting SKU in search.

Note : SKU are not in the product title. So I need to create a custom query.

```
 function SearchFilter($query) {

  if ($query->is_search) {

    $meta_query_args = array(
      'relation' => 'OR',
      array(
        'key' => '_sku',
        'value' => $query->query_vars['s'],
        'compare' => '=',
      )
    );

    $query->set('post_type', array('post','page', 'product'));
    $query->set('post_status', array('publish'));
    $query->set('meta_query', $meta_query_args);
  }
  
  return $query;

}
add_filter('pre_get_posts','SearchFilter');
```

**The problem :** When I place this code and I print the current SQL request, it gives me something like this.

```
    SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  bhd_posts.ID FROM bhd_posts  INNER JOIN bhd_postmeta ON ( bhd_posts.ID = bhd_postmeta.post_id ) WHERE 1=1  AND (((bhd_posts.post_title LIKE '%96242-20VH%') OR (bhd_posts.post_excerpt LIKE '%96242-20VH%') OR (bhd_posts.post_content LIKE '%96242-20VH%')))  AND (bhd_posts.post_password = '')  AND ( 
      ( bhd_postmeta.meta_key = '_sku' AND bhd_postmeta.meta_value = '96242-20VH' )
    ) AND bhd_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'product') AND ((bhd_posts.post_status = 'publish')) GROUP BY bhd_posts.ID ORDER BY bhd_posts.post_title LIKE '%96242-20VH%' DESC, bhd_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

As you can see, it tries to fetch for the "classic part" in the table `x_posts` for `post_title` OR `post_excerpt` OR `post_content` **AND** it must have a `meta_value` of my SKU.

As told above, my product titles do not have the sku in them.

**Goal :** Having to search in titles, excerpt, content or in meta_value OR search exclusivly with the meta_value.

Comment: Why are you using a filter and `me_replace_and_with_or` for your meta query instead of using the `relation` parameter set to `OR`? It's extremely unusual. Keep in mind that attachments don't appear in WordPress search out of the box, they have to be explicitly added to search somehow

Comment: I am just trying to figuring out why  `OR` is still returning `AND` on the query.

Comment: I can see that from your question, but, the presence of the  SQL filter is a major part that cannot be ignored or glossed over, and is super critical. It's directly related to this, and is the most suspicious part of your code, and the most probably cause of your problem. We need to know what it does and why it's there to answer the question.

Comment: By default WooCommerce SKU are not in the search query on the frontend (only backend). I want people on the frontend to be able to search by SKU (meta_key `_sku`). But when I call a "default" search query, it gives the above code. I am now trying to edit the search query to add the meta value in it. Also, I am not interested in using a plugin.

Comment: I see, you don't need the SQL filter for that though, `meta_query` already does that. Also keep in mind that plugin recommendations are off-topic here, asking for a plugin would get your question closed as offtopic.

Comment: Not sure to understand what you are saying. If I run a simple search query, it only fetch in the table `x_posts` for `post_title` OR `post_excerpt` OR `post_content`.

Comment: That's what `pre_get_posts` are for though, and that's why you add `meta_query`. You should have asked how to include search results for posts with a meta value, not how to exclude attachments from search. Most people will see the title and devise a solution around removing `attachment` from the `post_type` array, which isn't what you're trying to do

Comment: I understand! Anyways, using `meta_query` un the `pre_get_posts` still not work because the `AND` condition break everything. Looks like my `relation => 'OR'` is not working.

Comment: However I strongly suspect that what you literally want and what you actually want are not the same. You've literally asked how to search for post meta. But this means if a post mentions the SKU in the title, but not in the post meta, it will not appear in search. I suspect you actually do want it to appear in search, is that the case?

Comment: Also, `relation` refers to the various clauses of the meta query, but you only have a single clause, so the `relation` parameter is meaningless in this situation, can you explain further what you mean by the relation? Has this (post meta key equals SKU ) OR ( ????)

Comment: If the goal is to be able to search for posts that do not mention the SKU, but have that SKU in their post meta, AND posts that mention the SKU but do not have  that SKY in their post meta, then the answer is this cannot be done with WP_Query. For that kind of functionality you need a custom search solution, most likely something similar to Elastic Search. You also need to be very, very clear, and very specific about what you want when asking. In the meantime, update your question so you're asking about what you want, not how to fix the broken fix

Comment: Tried to update the question and my process. Hope it will be clearer.

Answer (score 7):

If you are using wordpress search you can add this code to make it work

```
function search_by_sku( $search, &$query_vars ) {
    global $wpdb;
    if(isset($query_vars->query['s']) && !empty($query_vars->query['s'])){
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page'  => -1,
            'post_type'       => 'product',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );
        $posts = get_posts($args);
        if(empty($posts)) return $search;
        $get_post_ids = array();
        foreach($posts as $post){
            $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
        }
        if(sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
                $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
        }
    }
    return $search;
    
}
    add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_sku', 999, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this code. Just to let you know that I tried it but it generates a PHP warning: "Parameter 2 to search_by_sku() expected to be a reference, value given"

Comment: @JulienVan how you are calling it ?

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep, so I couldn't comment, but here's the edit;

The code by @ahsankhan seems to work, but as reported, it was giving a "parameter 2" error.

If you remove the "**&**" from the first line where "**&$query_vars**" and replace with just "$query_vars" this seems to work without throwing any errors.

```
function search_by_sku( $search, $query_vars ) {
global $wpdb;
if(isset($query_vars->query['s']) && !empty($query_vars->query['s'])){
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page'  => -1,
        'post_type'       => 'product',
        'meta_query' => array(
            array(
                'key' => '_sku',
                'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                'compare' => 'LIKE'
            )
        )
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    if(empty($posts)) return $search;
    $get_post_ids = array();
    foreach($posts as $post){
        $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
    }
    if(sizeof( $get_post_ids ) > 0 ) {
            $search = str_replace( 'AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode( ',', $get_post_ids ) . ")) OR (", $search);
    }
}
return $search;
}
  add_filter( 'posts_search', 'search_by_sku', 999, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
// modded for search by sku in variation to ;)

function search_by_sku($search, &$query_vars)
{
    global $wpdb;
    if (isset($query_vars->query['s']) && !empty($query_vars->query['s'])) {
        // simple
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'product',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );

        $posts = get_posts($args);
        $get_post_ids = array();

        foreach ($posts as $post) {
            $get_post_ids[] = $post->ID;
        }


        // variation
        $args = array(
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_type' => 'product_variation',
            'meta_query' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => '_sku',
                    'value' => $query_vars->query['s'],
                    'compare' => 'LIKE'
                )
            )
        );

        $posts_variation = get_posts($args);
        
        if (empty($posts_variation) && empty($posts)) return $search;

        foreach ($posts_variation as $post) {
            $get_post_ids[] = $post->post_parent;
        }

        if (sizeof($get_post_ids) > 0) {
            $search = str_replace('AND (((', "AND ((({$wpdb->posts}.ID IN (" . implode(',', $get_post_ids) . ")) OR (", $search);
        }
    }
    return $search;

}

add_filter('posts_search', 'search_by_sku', 999, 2);
```